# CRM2011: create a role that is able to delete invoice products, but not able to delete the invoice

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

[image]Is that possible to define a security role that is not able to delete any invoice but able to delete invoiceproduct of any invoice?

The environment is not customized, and the definition( Tab:Mscrm.Form.invoicedetail.MainTab-->Group:Mscrm.Form.invoicedetail.MainTab.Groups-->Group:Mscrm.Form.invoicedetail.MainTab.Save-->Controls:Mscrm.Form.invoicedetail.MainTab.Save.Controls) for the ribbon button is

```
<Button Id="Mscrm.Form.invoicedetail.Delete" ToolTipTitle="$Resources:Mscrm_Form_Other_MainTab_Management_Delete_ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$Resources(EntityDisplayName):Ribbon.Form.Tooltip.Delete" Command="Mscrm.DeletePrimaryRecord" Sequence="70" LabelText="$Resources:Ribbon.HomepageGrid.MainTab.Management.Delete" Alt="$Resources:Ribbon.HomepageGrid.MainTab.Management.Delete" Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/Delete_16.png" Image32by32="/_imgs/Workplace/remove_32.png" TemplateAlias="o2" ModernImage="Remove" />
```

And the corresponding Command Definition is

```
  <CommandDefinition Id="Mscrm.DeletePrimaryRecord">
    <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.FormStateNotNew" />
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.EntityFormIsEnabled" />
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.CanDeletePrimary" />
    </EnableRules>
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.DeletePrimaryEntityPermission" />
    </DisplayRules>
    <Actions>
      <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="onActionMenuClick" Library="/_static/_forms/form.js">
        <StringParameter Value="delete" />
        <CrmParameter Value="PrimaryEntityTypeCode" />
      </JavaScriptFunction>
    </Actions>
  </CommandDefinition>
```

It seems it is not able to create such a role meet the requirement.
because 
1. In the 'displayrule' section, it needs 'Mscrm.DeletePrimaryEntityPermission' permission.
2. In the 'enablerule' section, it needs 'CanDeletePrimary' permission.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's not possible using OOB functions. I would suggest to develop the plugin that will handle Delete message of invoiceproduct and throw an exception if user doesn't have required role.

Comment: what is OOB functions?

Comment: OOB - Out Of Box. I meant  that that could not be done without development.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Is it able to accomplish it by defining a custom command definition , something like Mscrm.DeleteSecondaryRecord, and define displayrule and enablerule?

Comment: I believe that is possible.